# showing that $f_n(x)= x^n$ is no Cauchy Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces

Considering the space $C^0([0,1])$ of continuous functions on $[0,1]$, with the norm $||f|| = \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)|$ I have to determine whether $f_n(x) = x^n, n \in \mathbb N$ is a cauchy sequence or not. My intuition tells me it is not.
My question is now: How can I show that $$\left(\frac N m \right)^{\frac{N}{m-N}}-\left(\frac N m \right)^{\frac{m}{m-N}} \to 1$$ if $m \to \infty$?

---

### Some background

(In case you find an easier way.)

I am assuming it is a CS, so for $\varepsilon = 1/2$ I assume there is an $N$ such that $$||f_n - f_m|| < \epsilon \forall n,m \geq N$$, and now want to find a contradiction. Fixing $N=n$ I tried to show that we can make $||f_N-f_m|| = \max ( x^N - x^m)$ get arbitrarily close to 1 if we choose $m$ big enough. For that I determined the maximum of $x^N-x^m$ is at $x = \left(\frac n m \right)^{\frac{1}{m-n}}$ via setting the derivative to zero.
Plugging this back into the expression of the norm, I got to that question.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way is noticing that, pointwise,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x=1\\0&\text{if }0\le x<1\end{cases}$$ which is not in $C^0[0,1]$. If $f_n$ were Cauchy, then it would converge uniformly to a continuous function and, therefore, pointwise.

Comment: @flawr Are you sure the limit is $1$?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I meant the one the O.P. mentions. I completely agree with your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A computational (low-tech) answer:

$$\begin{split}
\left(\frac Nm\right)^{\frac{N}{m-N}} &= \left(\frac N{(m-N)+N}\right)^{\frac{N}{m-N}}\\
&=\left(\frac 1{\frac{m-N}{N} +1}\right)^{\frac{N}{m-N}} \\
&\to 1
\end{split}
$$

as $m\to \infty$. While the other term tends to $0$. So

$$\left(\frac N m \right)^{\frac{N}{m-N}}-\left(\frac N m \right)^{\frac{m}{m-N}} \to 1$$

as $m\to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to show there is some $\epsilon_0 >0$ such that for every $n$ there is some $m > n$ with $\lVert f_m - f_n \rVert > \epsilon_0$.

Choose $\epsilon_0 = 1/4$ and $m = 2n$.

Note that for $x_n = (1/2)^{1/n}$ we have $\lVert f_m-f_n \rVert \geqslant |x_n^{2n}-x_n^{n}| = 1/4$.

Answer (score 0):

A uniformly Cauchy sequence is pointwise convergent, and it uniformly converges to that pointwise limit.

The pointwise limit of the $\{f_n\}$ is $0$ on $(0,1)$ and $1$ at $1$.  Since a uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous, this is a contradiction.  Your sequence is not uniformly Cauchy.